# counts iteration in a nest for-loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, iteration, big-o, counting

Here is the pseudo code:

```
for i=1 to n
   for j=1 to n
     for k=1 to j
       x = x+1
```

and I have to calculate these two thing (i) count it precisely (ii) find it big-O

in (i), my final answer is n^4+2n^3+5n^2+4n+2. 
in (ii), because there are three loop, so it's O(n^3);

It seem that there must be an error either (i) or (ii) since (i) raise to the power 4, and the big-O is just 3.

Here is my step when counting the iteration:

```
for(i=1; i <=n; i++)
```

count as 1+(n+1)+n which is (2n+2).

So, (2n+2)+n(2n+2)+n(4+6+8+...+2n+2)+n^2(1+2+3+...+n)(2)
which finally come out with n^4(see the last term, sum of AS * n).

Comment: Your computation in (i) is incorrect. It is `O(n^3)` so it cannot have an `n^4` term

Answer (score 0):

For counting the number of iterations of the inner loop for nested loops like these, Sigma notation is a convenient tool

[image]

Since we count the number of iterations of the inner loop by equality (i.e., exactly, no inequalities), we can state the stronger big-Θ property for the asymptotic behaviour of the algorithm. This is under the assumption that we define `x = x + 1` to be a *basic operation* of your algorithm (which is appropriate here).

For your algorithm---say `T`---naturally `T ∈ Θ(n^3)` implies the upper and lower asymptotic bounds, `T ∈ O(n^3)` and `T ∈ Ω(n^3)`, respectively.